# ASP.NET & jsTree

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jstree

I have this repeater:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptContentPageGetAll" runat="server" OnLoad="rptContentPagesGetAll_Load">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <ul class="contentPageTree">
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li><%# Eval("title") %></li>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </ul>
        </FooterTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

and I tried the core code in Scripts.js:

```
jQuery(".contentPageTree")
.jstree({
    core : { },
    plugins : [ "themes", "html_data", "some-other-plugin" ]
});
```

Nothing was working, I tried looking around and anything i found didn't work. Can anyone help me getting started?

Also my js structure is as followed:

js

-> jsTree.v.1.0

->-> jQuery.jstree.js

jquery.min.js

scripts.js

and yes I am including the js files in my master page

```
<script language="javascript" src="../js/jsTree.v.1.0/_lib/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="../js/jsTree.v.1.0/jquery.jstree.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="../js/jsTree.v.1.0/_lib/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="../js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Check if there are any problems in referencing the JS files.
- I didn't quite get your scripts order. You should have jQuery very first, then the tree script, then your own at the last
- Did you try it in HTML page with all the core options and plugins and JS order? This should help.

Comment: That was the order in the folders not in order on the actual files.